# why only one is write it characteristics in a loop?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

may be my question is wrong.but in the following code only one is write to output other is not showing.but both are in same loop.please help me.

```
            private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {


           timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
             secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
             mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
             milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
           if(secs==0  ){
            Log.v("__in__if_secs_____", "_______"+secs);
               byte[] val={1};
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);

             customHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
             logd.append("\nWrite at Time:"+secs+" secs"+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }

           else if(secs==1 ){
               Log.v("__in__if_secs_____", "_______"+secs);
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n  Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }


           else if(secs==2 ){
               Log.v("__in__if_secs_____", "_______"+secs);
               byte[] val={1};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }

           else if(secs==3 ){
               byte[] val={0};
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }

           else if(secs==4 ){
               byte[] val={1};
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\nWrite at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }


           else if(secs==5 ){

               Log.v("__in__if_secs_____", "_______"+secs);
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\nWrite at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }
           else if(secs==6 ){
               byte[] val={1};
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 2000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }

           else if(secs==8 && milliseconds<500){
               byte[] val={0};
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 500);
             logd.append("\nWrite at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }


           else if(secs==8 && milliseconds>=500){
               byte[] val={1};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1); 
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 2000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

           else if(secs==10   ){
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
                 mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 600);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

           else if(secs==11 ){
               byte[] val={1};

               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 2200);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }


           else if(secs==13  && milliseconds<500 ){
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 500);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

        // 3rd
           else if(secs==13 && milliseconds>=500 ){
               byte[] val={1};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1); 
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
         customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

           else if(secs==14 ){
              byte[] val={0};
              mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
              mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }


           else if(secs==15  ){
               byte[] val={1};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1); 
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

           else if(secs==16 ){
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }

           else if(secs==17   ){
               byte[] val={1};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

           }


           else if(secs==18  ){
               byte[] val={0};
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);
               mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);

       customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,1000);
             logd.append("\n Write at Time:"+secs+" secs "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");
           }

           else if(secs<19) {
               customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
               }

           else if(secs==19) {
               startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
               }
        }
```

};

only one bluetooth service is writing other is not.in the above code the runnale will continues to run upto 19 seconds but only one bluetooth service port is writing other didnot writing but i am getting result in logcat as true.why.please solve this.

Comment: You have to wait for the first write to complete via the callback.  The api is set up to be asynchronous but it is not really and the docs don't tell you...

Comment: i am new to this so please let me know how to callback.